# What do you call this fragment?

Tags: phrases, sentence, syntactic-analysis

> He looked out over the ocean and felt closer, **this dawn**, than ever before, closer to the heart of it all.

From the "Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows" by J. K. Rowling

The author described the dawn few sentences before this sentence. So it is clear form the context what dawn she is talking about; however, I struggle to identify this fragment. What do you call it? A phrase of some sort?

Comment: Maybe *anaphora*?

Comment: It is not a fragment. It is an adjunct of time; it identifies when he felt closer than ever before ...It is, more precisely a **supplementary adjunct**, separated by commas from the surrounding text and presented as a separate unit of information, parenthetical or additional.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got confused because I used to see sentences with "at dawn" not "this dawn" but I guess they both answer - when? question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly claimed it to be a fragment, when in fact it is an supplementary adjunct to the notion of time in this context.

> an **adjunct** is an optional, or structurally dispensable, part of a sentence, clause, or phrase that, if removed or discarded, will not otherwise affect the remainder of the sentence. 
>   (Wikipedia)

It adds more information to the sentence by stressing it's time aspect.

Comment: That looks awfully like an unnamed citation. Furthermore your answer states the same as a previous comment on the question without really adding any value information to the comment's.